# Maximum allowed amount of tokens

Tags: contract-development, tokens

I would like to create a token which any wallet cannot hold more than 100 of.

Is this possible while this token, also is mintable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

I'm not sure if you mean that there should never be more than 100 tokens total, or if no one wallet should be able to have a balance of more than 100 tokens. We'll go through both.

### Token with only 100 total tokens

First, you mentioned a `mint` function. I assume this means you understand that without `mint`, it's pretty simple - just premint 100 tokens and there's no way to make more.

It's still pretty simple even with a `mint` function.

The [ERC20 standard](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/) specifies a `totalSupply()` which is used to show how many tokens are in circulation.

If you query `totalSupply` in `mint` (before you actually mint the token), you can see how many tokens are already in circulation. (Remember to adjust for the decimals. If you have 18 decimal places, and `totalSupply()` returns `1`, it doesn't mean 1 token, it means 0.000000000000000001 tokens.) If there are already 100 tokens, `mint` should revert, if there are less than 100, but the amount to mint would push it over 100, it should mint `100 - totalSupply` tokens, and otherwise, the full amount.

### Token where no one address can hold more than 100

This works very similar to the above, but instead of using `totalSupply`, you'll use the `balance` of the address receiving the tokens. (There is a function `balanceOf` which takes an address as an argument which you can use.) Note that here you'll need checks in `mint` and also in `transfer` and `transferFrom`. (If there is an internal `_transfer` function used by both, like in OpenZeppelin's ERC20, putting the checks in `_transfer` should be enough for both.)

Hope that helps!